# javascript : Lazy loading for images using eventlistener and debounce

Tags: javascript

I have several `div` with class `'comp'`. Each comp has images inside. What I want to achieve is to implement lazy loading for images insdie each `comp`. So, that when a specific `comp` element enters in the viewport I want the images to be loaded.

I want to use eventlistener and debounce as a polyfill approach as I tried the intersection observer DOM API but it has a limitation i.e. it is not supported by some recent Safari and IE versions.

Any help in this regards will be really appreciated.

**Code:**

```
const options = {
    threshold: 0
};
const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      loadImage(entry.target);
      entry.target.classList.add('loaded');
      io.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
}, options);

const targetElements = document.querySelectorAll(".comp");
for (let element of targetElements) {
    if (document.body.className.match(/\bintersection-observer-supported\b/)) {
        io.observe(element);
    } else {
        var domRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    }
}

function loadImage(imageElement) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.dir(imageElement.querySelector('img'));
    imageElement.querySelector('img.target-image').src = imageElement.querySelector('img.target-image').dataset.src;
  }, 500);
}
//Polyfill
function elementInViewport(el) {
  var top = el.offsetTop;
  var left = el.offsetLeft;
  var width = el.offsetWidth;
  var height = el.offsetHeight;
  while(el.offsetParent) {
    el = el.offsetParent;
    top += el.offsetTop;
    left += el.offsetLeft;
  }

  return (
    top < (window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight) &&
    left < (window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth) &&
    (top + height) > window.pageYOffset &&
    (left + width) > window.pageXOffset
  );
}
```

Comment: We're using `IntersectionObservers` in prod for quite some time now using this polyfill: https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill.

You might want to give it a try first.

Comment: Instead of the Intersection Observer API, you can use [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for the same purpose. At a high level, I would have the image source be listed as a `data-src` attribute, and then when it's within the viewport, or about to be, use `setAttribute` to set the image's `src`. Happy to help once you have some code.

Comment: I would prefer using the Intersection Observer API instead of getBoundingClientRect.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah any specific reason

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah how do you handle the cross browser compatibility

Comment: @NickHTTPS do not want to use that. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Sami The reason to prefer Intersection Observer API over getBoundingClientRect is due to performance. Enjoy this read https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/01/deferring-lazy-loading-intersection-observer-api/

Comment: @sami whatever you are going to implement it will be pretty much what it's already included in that polifyll. They use debounce and all the nice stuff on `addEvent(document, 'scroll', this._checkForIntersections, true);` So I'm not sure why you so against it.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I updated the question with code

Comment: @NickHTTPS I agree its a very useful stuff but we are restricted by not adding any further third party libraries

Comment: @Sami - Can you create a more complete example that can be executed directly in your question? Also included what you'd like it to do and what it's currently doing.